# How to dispose of an SWT Font set on a Draw2D Label?

Tags: java, swt, dispose, eclipse-gef, draw2d

In a GEF editor, I have the following `EditPart`:

```
public class MyLabelEditPart extends AbstractGraphicalEditPart {

@Override
protected IFigure createFigure() {
    return new Label();
}

@Override
protected void refreshVisuals() {
    MyModel model = (MyModel) getModel();
    Label figure = (Label) getFigure();
    EditPart parent = getParent();

    Font font = new Font(Display.getCurrent(), "sansserif", 11, SWT.BOLD);
    figure.setFont(font);
    figure.setForegroundColor(ColorConstants.darkGray);
    figure.setText(model.getValueString());
    parent.refresh();
}
```

All works fine with most models, but - you will have spotted the error already - I never dispose of the font. So, with a large-ish model of 10k+ tokens, this throws an `org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles`. At least I think (hope) this is what causes the error.

Now I cannot figure out how to dispose the font, as the figure for the EditPart is a Draw2D Label, not an SWT Widget. How can I make sure the dreaded error can be circumvented?

Comment: So you're creating the same font over and over again instead of making it `static` and reusing it?

Comment: Ouch! Thanks for the pointer! Forest/Trees... Guess using a `FontRegistry` would be another solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from [Baz' solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20398160/how-to-dispose-of-an-swt-font-set-on-a-draw2d-label?noredirect=1#comment30460371_20398160) to make the font a static field, a good solution is to use a JFace `FontRegistry`, as detailed in [this strangeoptics blog post](http://strangeoptics.blogspot.de/2011/09/eclipse-rcp-all-my-registries.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep and reuse all your resources ( images, fonts, colors..etc) at one point rather than using registries, follow this windows builder class

http://code.google.com/p/goclipse/source/browse/trunk/goclipse-n/src/org/eclipse/wb/swt/SWTResourceManager.java?r=445